# unsigned long long int pow

Tags: c, math, integer, long-integer, exponentiation

I have the following power function which operates on integers and it works fine:

```
int ipow( int base, int exp )
{
    int result = 1;
    while( exp )
    {
        if ( exp & 1 )
        {
            result *= base;
        }
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I'd like to have a version which allows exp > 32. So I use unsigned long long ints:

```
unsigned long long int ipow( int base, int exp )
{
    unsigned long long int result = 1ULL;
    while( exp )
    {
        if ( exp & 1 )
        {
            result *= (unsigned long long int)base;
        }
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But this second version doesn't seem to work:

```
unsigned long long int x;
x = ipow( 2, 35 );
printf( "%llu\n", x );
```

this will output 0.

What's the problem with my unsigned long long int implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `base` variable is too small. Change it to `unsigned long long int`, like the others, since it holds numbers greater than `2^32`.

Answer (score 2):

Section 6.5p4 of the C standard:

> Some operators (the unary operator ~, and the binary operators <<, >>,
>   &, ^, and |, collectively described as bitwise operators) are required
>   to have operands that have integer type. These operators yield values
>   that depend on the internal representations of integers, and have
>   implementation-defined and undefined aspects for signed types.

Section 6.5p5 of the C standard:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an
>   expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or
>   not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior
>   is undefined.

If it seemed like a good idea to use `int` in this code before, it shouldn't now. Both of these sections are saying that your code isn't as portable as it could be.

Comment: Which part of the code is against the quoted parts of the standard?

Comment: @MichałTrybus Well, 6.5p5 is the logic behind your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For large numbers, it is better to unsigned long long base since in the process of squaring base in my overflow integer type.

```
unsigned long long int ipow(int base_i, int exp )
    {
      unsigned long long int base = (unsigned long long int) base_i;
      unsigned long long int result = 1ULL;
      while( exp )
      {
          if ( exp & 1 )
          {
              result *= (unsigned long long int)base;
          }
          exp >>= 1;
          base *= base;
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Then, ipow(2,62) would give the correct answer. ipow(2,63) is already too large (in my system), even though the unsigned long long int should be able to handle approximately 2^64-1.