# pow function not working properly in Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c, codeblocks, pow, math.h

I have got a question from my junior and I can't fix it. Following is the code he is using in the Code::Blocks IDE just downloaded from official site of [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

It's a hello world console project, which he just modified a little, using the header file `math.h` and using `pow()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world! %d\n",pow(2,2));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code should be `Hello world! 4` right? But voila it's always `Hello world! 0` *unless* I use `printf("Hello world! %f\n", pow(2,2));` which is syntactically, yeah perfect and the right thing to do. But then it's another story altogether.

Pow function should return 4, `double`, of course. So what is happening? `printf()` is not working correctly, or there is some issue with `pow()`.

Comment: The return value is `double` so you have to cast it to `(int)`

Comment: If you are using GCC, add `-Wall` and you'd be told about the mismatch between the `%d` format and the `double` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("Hello world! %d\n",pow(2,2));`
"The output of this code should be Hello world! 4 right?"

No.  As this is undefined behavior, anything can happen.  As [@Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333397/2410359) posted what likely happens in this errant situation, you could have a possible understanding of why you saw 0.  But in the end, C does not have to perform this way.

> ... If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined..  C11 §7.21.6.1 9

Casting to `(int)` is a problem too.

1) `int` range is much smaller than `double` and for `pow(2,100)`, that fails.

2) Casting to `int` truncates the fractional portion on the result of `double` and the preciseness of `pow()` is not defined.  This will given surprising result when the `pow()` is something like `7.99999999999999` and `7` is printed rather than the hoped for `8.000000`.

If code needs an integer power function, consider [unsigned long long int pow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224911/unsigned-long-long-int-pow) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/213897/2410359 or search around.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `pow()` is `double` as you can see here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm

So you have to cast the return value to int like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world! %d\n",(int)pow(2,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise as you saw is the output 0!

Another example to show this you can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world! %d\n",4.000000);
    return 0;
}
```

As you will see the output is also 0 because it's a double value!

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, `pow` returns a double. `printf`, however, has no awareness of the types passed to it in the stack, and if you pass a `double` where an `int` is expected, it will simply take the first `sizeof(int)` bytes from the stack and interpret them as an `int`. 
E.g., on my machine (gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) on x86_64), this program printed `Hello world! -1954378952`.

If you want to treat the result as an `int` by using `%d`, you should explicitly cast it as such:

```
printf("Hello world! %d\n", (int)pow(2,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

`pow(2,2)` will return a double always.

In `printf()` %d and %i both are used for printing an int.If you use %d or %i for a double it will create problems.
In order to display a double use %f or %lf it will give you correct answer

```
    printf("Hello world! %f\n",pow(2,2));
```

or

```
    printf("Hello world! %lf\n",pow(2,2));
```