# Unsigned Long Int overflow when calculating pow

Tags: c, multiplication, exponential, unsigned-long-long-int

I am trying to make a function that quickly calculates x^y mod z. It works well when calculating something like 2^63 mod 3, but at 2^64 mod 3 and higher exponents it just returns 0.

I am suspecting an overflow somewhere, but I can't pin it down. I have tried explicit casts at the places where calculations  (* and mod) are made, I have also made my storage variables (`resPow`, `curPow`) `unsigned long long int` (as Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224911/unsigned-long-long-int-pow)) but that didn't help much.

```
typedef unsigned long int lint;

lint fastpow(lint nBase, lint nExp, lint nMod) { 
    int lastTrueBit = 0;
    unsigned long long int resPow = 1ULL;

    unsigned long long int curPow = nBase;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        int currentBit = getBit(nExp, i);

        if (currentBit == 1) {
            for (lint j = 0; j < i - lastTrueBit; j++) {
                curPow = curPow * curPow;
            }
            resPow =resPow * curPow;
            lastTrueBit = i;
        }
    }
    return resPow % nMod;
}
```

Comment: Why are you only doing `% nMod` at the end? That defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: You can calculate `2^64 mod 3` with `unsigned` **`char`**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am suspecting an overflow somewhere,

Yes, both `curPow * curPow` and `resPow * curPow` may mathematically overflow.

The usual way to contain overflow here is to perform   *mod* on intermediate products.

```
        // curPow = curPow * curPow;
        curPow = (curPow * curPow) % nMod;
    // resPow =resPow * curPow;
    resPow = (resPow * curPow) % nMod;
```

---

This is sufficient when `nMod < ULLONG_MAX/(nMod - 1)`.  (The mod value is half the precision of `unsigned long long`).  Otherwise more extreme measures are needed as in: [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485).

---

Minor stuff

`for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)` assumes `lint/unsigned long` is 32 bits.  Portable code would avoid that *magic number*.  `unsigned long` is 64-bits on various platforms.

`LL` is not needed here.  `U` remains useful to quiet various compiler warnings.

```
// unsigned long long int resPow = 1ULL;
unsigned long long int resPow = 1U;
```